# Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\cos (x)=1$ with the epsilon-delta definition of limits

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Prove

$$    
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\cos (x)=1
$$

with the epsilon-delta definition of limits

Comment: this is actually quite difficult. It is not apparent to me how to manipulated $|\cos (x)-1|$ to $|x|$

Comment: @OriaGruber: Would breaking cosine into its second order Taylor Polynomial about $x_0=0$ work? That would change $\cos x$ into $1-\frac{1}{2}x^2$.

Comment: @OriaGruber: I dont know if it is posible to use taylor expansion, maybe we could get something from that, but Im afraid to sacrify formality.

Comment: Why stop at second order? If you really want to be as accurate and rigorous as possible, you will have to go to "nth" order.

Comment: @OriaGruber: So there is no clue? I have just recieved an answer, but I have got problems understanding the reasoning. Could you please check it out

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: So there is no clue? I have just recieved an answer, but I have got problems understanding the reasoning. Could you please check it out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We want to  show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-0|\lt \delta$, then $|1-\cos x|\lt \epsilon$.

To do this, we need an estimate of $|1-\cos x|$ for $x$ close to $0$. 
Suppose that $|x|\lt 1$.

Multiplying top and (missing) bottom by $1+\cos x$  (which is $\gt 1$ in our interval), we get 
$$|1-\cos x|=\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\cos x}.\tag{1}$$ 
In our interval, we have $\cos x\gt 0$, and therefore 
$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\cos x}\le \sin^2 x.\tag{2}$$
It is always true that $|\sin x|\le x$. It follows from (1) and (2) that in our interval,
$$|1-\cos x|\le x^2\le x.\tag{3}$$
Finally, we have the required estimate. Let $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon)$. Making sure that $\delta\le 1$ is just to make sure that we are working in the interval $|x|\le 1$, since our inequality was derived under the assumption $|x|\le 1$. It is protection against someone giving us a ridiculous $\epsilon$, such as $\epsilon=10$.

If $|x|\lt \delta$, then by Inequality (3) we have  $|1-\cos x|\lt |x|\lt \delta=\epsilon$, so $|1-\cos x|\lt \epsilon$.

In fact we have the stronger inequality $|1-\cos x|\le x^2$. So we could have chosen $\delta$ to be the minimum of $1$ and $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

**Remark:** An approach similar to the one in the answer may be intended. There are, however, issues, since the inequality was obtained by using "informal" geometric facts. For a fully formal approach, we should have a formal definition of $\cos x$, say via the power series. But then the result follows from general facts about power series.

Comment: So @AndréNicolas the final expresion would be. $$\left|\frac{x}{1+\cos x}\right|$$ and which would be the final argument to conclude the result?. Im not seing very clear the road.!!

Comment: I made a little jump. In our interval $1+\cos x\gt 1$, so, as I wrote, $|1-\cos x|\le |x|$. That means we can take $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon$.

Comment: Please @AndréNicolas it is not trivial for me, sorry for that, could you please write me the sequence to have a better vision of the reasoning.

Comment: I will add detail to the answer. It will take a while (1/2 hour?), I have something else to finish.

Comment: Ok: @AndréNicolas thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $0\leq 1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\leq2|\sin\frac{x}{2}|\leq|x|$, then:

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta=\epsilon>0$, s.t. $\forall x, |x|<\delta, |1-\cos x|\left(\leq|x|<\delta\right)<\epsilon$.

Comment: "Note"? How other than using derivatives? And what the absolute value in the left hand for? We certainly have $\;1-\cos x\ge 0\;$ for **all** $\;x\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc: I have edited again.

Comment: It looks better, yet still there is the $\;|\sin x|\le |x|\;$ inequality, but this one is better known than the other one, and in fact can be proved geometrically. Nice. +1

Comment: @Timbuc: You can also prove the inequality by use the Mean value Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem, and $1-\cos x=\sin(\theta x)x\leq|x|$.

Comment: Indeed so, @Alfred, yet the basic nature of the question made me think the OP probably hasn't yet studied derivatives so it'd be better to avoid them when possible.